# gmaps4rails Conditional validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I am using Gmaps4Rails on my User model.

I want to use the validation functionality, but I don't want the validation during signup.
So I did this:

```
acts_as_gmappable :validation => false
```

Then I realized that I really would like this validation after the signup.

but I am uncertain about How can I implement conditional validation for gmaps4rails?

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: using Gmaps4Rails.set_gmaps4rails_options!({:validation => false}) ? may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned in [the doc](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Model-Customization), you can use a Proc:

```
acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding: lambda {|user| !user.new_record? }
```

Comment: I am totally new with the usage of Proc and lambda. Worse I didn't even remember about new_record? method. I am shameless, but somehow I do manage to get somewhere. I would recommend a "Conditional validation" section. But again no complaints. Thx again